# Div won't fade out/fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to get a div to fade out and in on button click. It works on jfiddle but for some reason it is not working on my asp.net page:

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){    
    $('#fancy').fadeOut('slow', function(){
       $('#fancy').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

<div><a href="#" id="btn">fade div</a></div>
<div id="fancy">Fancy Div</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/1859/

my asp.net page:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" class="init">


    $('#btn').click(function (e) {
        $('#fancy').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#fancy').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div><a href="#" id="btn">Fade div</a></div> 
<div id="fancy">Fancy Div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code on the asp.net page?

Comment: is jQuery included on your page?

Comment: is JQuery and JQueryUI included in your page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put your jQuery code inside the head section and try to manipulate the DOM elements it won't work as at that time your HTML document isn't loaded yet. So you have two ways to resolve this issue.

**First** : Use *$(document).ready()* function and put your code inside it. So whenever your document is ready, *$(document).ready()* event will be fired.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function (e) {
        $('#fancy').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#fancy').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

**Second** : Put your jQuery code at bottom of your page.

Comment: Due to the fact you're click function wasn't defined within the $(document).ready(...) see - http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the page you have this implemented on? Hard to know what's going wrong without seeing the failing code. My first guess would be that jQuery isn't running on your page.

In the meantime, you could try throwing a log inside of your `click` function to see if that's firing.

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){    
    console.log('Click fired');
    $('#fancy').fadeOut('slow', function(){
       $('#fancy').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: I've updated the question with my asp.net page. I'll try the log thing now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have not done the binding:
try this code

```
$(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(e){    
    console.log('Click fired');
    $('#fancy').fadeOut('slow', function(){
       $('#fancy').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Sorry missed the previous post.