# Read textbox value from javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have created a google map with a bubble as the marker. I have created an array in code behind and set a textbox with these values. The textbox gets populated with the correct values, but I cannot read the values from jquery/javascript...

When using these statement:

```
    var markers = $('#txtMarkers').val();
     var markers =  document.getElementById('<%=txtMarkers.ClientID%>')
```

I get this error message:

```
    0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference
```

And when I use this :

```
    var markers = document.getElementById('<%=txtMarkers.ClientID%>').value;
```

I get this error message:

```
      0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference
```

But, the textbox is getting populated. This is what gets populated in the textbox (added manual values to see what is getting populated in the textbox):

```
    [{"title":"DRIVER","lat":"25.9820333333333","lng":"28.1289333333333","description":"0.6608917"},
    {"title":"DRIVER","lat":"-25.982","lng":"28.1289333333333","description":"0.6643902"},
    ...more values}]
```

Adding these values manually loads the map and markers, but it doesn't seem to read the values from the textbox. Am I doing something wrong?

---

### **More Information**

When I put the $(document).ready(function () {}); on the page I get an error of

```
    0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'initialize' is undefined
```

So I took the onload="initialize()" in the body tag out, thus resulting in this error:

```
    0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'lat' of undefined or null reference
```

in this piece of code since there is no information as a method has to run before this gets loaded (information from db):

```
     var mapOptions = {     
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng), 
              zoom: 8,
              mapTypeControl: true,
              panControl: true,
                zoomControl: true,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP         
          };
```

Comment: `$('#txtMarkers')` is this elem is available in the page there?

Comment: try putting your jQuery code inside $(document).ready(function(){}); function.

Comment: '<%=txtMarkers'.ClientID%>' - what the strange "thing" is that? At least it looks like there is extra `'` in the middle. Also there is no element with ID `<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>` in the page, as said in error message. Are you sure that IDs on page looks like that?

Comment: Hi, yes the element is available.. I have saved the error message before I renamed the textbox from TextBox1 to txtMarkers, thus just copied the same error message than before I changed the name of the textbox... I have updated it above.... When I use the document ready function I get this error: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'initialize' is undefined (initialize in my body tag: <body onload="initialize()" > ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get null or undefined value due to the fact that before loading the DOM element your client side script is asking for the value of that element.

**[Here's a similar scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499531/div-wont-fade-out-fade-in/24499670#24499670)**

Demo Application :

MyForm.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="_24733063.MyForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                alert($("#dataTextBox").val());
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="dataTextBox" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

MyForm.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataTextBox.Text = "some text values";
}
```